# How to merge multiple files in Java?

Tags: java

Is there a way I can merge multiple files together? for example

file1:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

File2:

```
4 D
5 E
6 F
```

MERGED TOGETHER OUTPUT

```
1 A 4 D
2 B 5 E
3 C 6 F
```

Comment: Basically just read from both files an write them together to another file

Comment: That is easy, just read from one file and `append` to the other.

Comment: What do you want to output to?

Comment: What happened to `3C` and `6F`? Why are they missing from the desired output?

Comment: I'm flagged this question as "unclear what you're asking". For explanation see the above comments.

Comment: @DavidS I wouldn't say the question is unclear. It gives enough information to be answered. It just doesn't say where the merged data should be put. That's irrelevant to the question, though. It's only relevant to the answers.

Comment: @4castle The OP has deleted some of his comments which added the confusion. His response to "Basically just read from both files and write them together to another file" was "I thought of that but I didn't want to create another file." If the OP has the knowledge to do as suggested, then what is the problem, exactly? Where is his attempt to do this, and what's not working?

Comment: @DavidS If he said that he tried `append`, then `append` is what's not working because it doesn't have the behavior he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for merging files adjacently is essentially:

1. **Read** the lines from the two files into two lists.
2. **Merge** the lines of the 2nd list onto those of the 1st list.
3. **Append** any additional lines in the 2nd list to the 1st list.
4. **Write** the 1st list to a file (or wherever).

Here's how I implemented that algorithm using Java 7:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MergeFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // READ file1 into lines1 & file2 into lines2
        final Charset CS = Charset.defaultCharset(); // e.g. UTF-8
        List<String> lines1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file1"), CS),
                     lines2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file2"), CS);

        // MERGE until end of either list, then APPEND until end of lines2
        for (int i = 0; i < lines2.size(); i++)
            if (i < lines1.size())
                lines1.set(i, lines1.get(i) + " " + lines2.get(i));
            else
                lines1.add(lines2.get(i));

        // WRITE lines1 (the merged lines) to some file3
        Files.write(Paths.get("file3"), lines1, CS,
                CREATE, WRITE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

Comment: In my code, I output to a `file3`, but you could just as easily output to `file1` or `file2`. Everything worked perfectly in my testing.